# wpf combo box and mvvm pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have been trying to bind a Combobox with a list and selectedvalue to be displayed on the UI when the user get on the screen.

What doesnt work: **SelectedValue does not appear**

**UI:**

```
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}"
                                     Grid.Row="1"                                         
                                     Width="219"                                         
                                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                     SelectedItem="{Binding SValue,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                     ItemsSource="{Binding SList,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                     SelectedValue="{Binding SValue,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                     DisplayMemberPath="Value"
                                     SelectedValuePath="Value"                                         
                                     Margin="0,8,0,7" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public List<StringKeyValue> SList
    {
        get { return _SList; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _SList, value); }
    }

public StringKeyValue SValue
    {
        get { return _SValue; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _SValue, value); }
    }

private List<StringKeyValue> _SList;

    private StringKeyValue _SValue;


SList.Add(new StringKeyValue() { Key = "00", Value = "--" });
SList.Add(new StringKeyValue() { Key = "01", Value = "Test Value" });

SList.Add(new StringKeyValue() { Key = "02", Value = "Test Value2" });
            SValue = SList[1];
```

There is no value that appears in the dropdown area, it is just blank
When clicking on the drop down i can see the values in the list:

1. --
2. Test Value(This one is highlighted since binded to SelectedItem)
3. Test Value2

If anyone could help me out thanks

Comment: If you have values in the dropdown then your binding is fine - if you want an initial value to be selected then put a default (initial) value into `SValue`.

Comment: Also, your `SList.Add()` calls should not cause new values to show up straight away - you are using a List and not an ObservableCollection, a List doesn't notify of changes so the binding subsystem will not automatically pick up new items.